# Android Manifest doesn't find <meta-data>

Tags: android, android-manifest, google-play-services, chromecast

I'm trying to configure my app to program Chromecast featured button.

I'm reading all chromecast SDK and it says that i have to install Google Play Services.
I linked the library to my project, at the same workspace. I did it well because I have a new Android Dependencies library called google_play_services.jar

When I reach this point, I want to test if googlePlayServices are available, so I want to use:

```
GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(getApplicationContext());
```

and print a Log with the result.

But the problem appeared here. When I  run my app, it says that  is not in my Android Manifest.

My Android Manifest has these lines already:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.chromecastAPP"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="9"
    android:targetSdkVersion="18" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

<meta-data 
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
    android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.chromecastAPP.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
</manifest>
```

Any different solution?

Thank you

Comment: post please your whole manifest file

Comment: post edited including all my Manifest

Comment: meta-data must be in applications tags

Comment: check my answer if it helped you, i post it below

Comment: Why I have negative votes? :S:S

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Meta-data must be in application tags.
"Edit your application's `AndroidManifest.xml` file, and add the following declaration within the `<application>` element. This embeds the version of Google Play services that the app was compiled with." Look [this](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start) link.
 Try this:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.chromecastAPP"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="9"
    android:targetSdkVersion="18" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>



<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.chromecastAPP.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
<meta-data 
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
    android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
</application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: Now your answer is perfect! +1 up from me.

Answer (score 0):

I also Faced this problem. I just updated my SDK **Google Play Service** with its update Version and it worked for me...
Try it may be it works for you also..

Comment: I updated all SDK google Play Services this morning before I start to include it to my app. This is not working for me. thank you

Comment: ok Then first add google play service jar file in your libs folder then right click on your project->properties->java build path->Libraries->add library->select library from your libs folder(which u added)->after that go to order and export->check your google play service library if its not checked..Hope it help you out..